# mapbox-gl-native license

Tags: commercial, bsd, attribution

[Mapbox-gl-native](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) is licensed under  [3-Clause BSD license](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/LICENSE.md).

The license states that we need to attribute mapbox in binary form.
Buts its not clear if we can mention within a menu of the app we make or it has to be on the map view even if we are to serve non-mapbox tiles.

Any help in clarifying this helps us.

Comment: When you say "commercial product" I guess you mean "binary distribution" of the software. The license says exactly: "Redistributions in binary form must reproduce [this license] *in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution*." If this is still not clear please expand your question about what part is still confusing.

Comment: Hi Brandin. The question is if we were to serve non-mapbox tiles, then does the attribution in the app menu (like about->legal ) is sufficient and not on the map view.

Comment: Maybe someone more familiar with mapbox can give you a specific suggestion. But the basic question has answers you may refer to: [Clarification of BSD's second clause - binary must reproduce copyright notice?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/clarification-of-bsds-second-clause-binary-must-reproduce-copyright-notice)

Comment: And [BSD 3-Clause: where to place license for binary installation?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/bsd-3-clause-where-to-place-license-for-binary-installation)

Comment: "even if we are to serve non-mapbox tiles" - This part of your clarified question seems like it doesn't relate to your question. Basically, if you are including mapbox (with BSD license) in your application and distributing that, then you need to abide by the Mapbox license. It doesn't matter if sometimes your application is not using the Mapbox functionality (by displaying "non-mapbox" tiles) and sometimes it is using it (by displaying "mapbox" tiles).

Comment: Brandin , please modify above comment as answer. so i can accept it

Comment: I think the answer is exactly already answered in [BSD 3-Clause: where to place license for binary installation?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/bsd-3-clause-where-to-place-license-for-binary-installation) so it would not add much to answer this yet again in a new way.